# Update attributes of user outside devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authenticating users. I have defined a score for a user that is updated over time. A separate controller takes care of updating the score. I use `@user.update_attributes(:score => new_score)` but the changes can't be saved. I am suspicious that is happening because user is a devise object.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Devise you probably have an `attr_accessible` line in your User model. This is a whitelist of attributes which can be updated via bulk assignment from hashes (with methods like update_attributes). You can do one of two things:

1. add :score to `attr_accessible`. This means that by default POSTing to the user edit screen with params[:user][:score] = x will update the user's score.
2. assign the score directly in your controller, via `@user.score = x`. Direct assignment is not affected by `attr_accessible`

Here's the doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

Comment: Hi! Well, I was using all this. You know the problem is that users were in place from long ago and the score is a new column that was recently added. So for all users that were created using devise sign up after adding score, I can manipulate and change score as you have mentioned. But for the old objects the database rolls back before saving which is weird. This won't have much impact on my application since it's not in production but I would love to know the reason for such behavior.